# Calculate map point in coordinates

Tags: applications, coordinate-systems

I am creating a map application and I need help in calculation.

[image: map]

I am having an image of map which is say 125px in height and 250px in width, I know coordinates of all the corners, now I want to find an offset for a point 80.25,12.5. How can I do that ? Can anyone suggest a formula for that ?

Please help.

Comment: Fair warning: "this is urgent" makes people more likely to not answer your question...

Comment: Ok I will keep in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need simple proportions. Your full height in pixels is $125px$; the height in your coordinate system is $80$, hence $12.5/80=X/125px$. More generally, if $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates in the original coordinate system and $X$ and $Y$ are the coordinates in the pixel space then $X=250px\times x/100$ and $Y=125px\times y/80$.

Comment: will this work if coordinates are not starting from 0,0, i.e. if top left corner has coordinates 10,10. then what will this formula work ?

Comment: No it won't. You'll need to subtract the coordinates of the top left corner.

Comment: Ok so the new formula could be something like X=250px*x0-x1/100 and Y=125x*y0-y1/80 correct ?

Comment: No, $X=250px\times (x-x_0)/100$ and $Y=125px\times (y-y_0)/80$. This assumes that $100$ and $80$ are your _full_ width and height.

Comment: perfect thank you so much :-)

Comment: @AlekseyPichugin maybe you can help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548841/calculate-point-coordinates