# Calculate Point Coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

As you can see, In the image a rectangle gets translated to another position in the coordinates System.

The origin Coordinates are `A1(8,2) B1(9,3)` from the length `7` and the height `3` you can also guess the vertices of the rectangle.

**Now the Rectangle gets moved**.

Now `A1` is at `A2(16,9)` and `B1` is located at  `B2(16,11)`.

It means that the rectangle got translated, rotated and stretched.

**How can I calculate the Coordinates, of the left-upper corner?**

[image]

---

*I first tried to calculate the stretching-factor but then I got stuck when I trying to calculate the angle and translation*

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: If the points $A1$ and $B1$ transform like you defined to $A2$ and $B2$, the other points you sketched in form of the original rectangle boundary will give a different transformed boundary than you drew. The drawing is not consistent with an affine transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses complex numbers.

We want to find $a,b,\theta\in\mathbb R$ where $0\lt\theta\lt \pi$ such that
$$(16+9i)-(a+bi)=\sqrt 2(8+2i)(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
$$(16+11i)-(a+bi)=\sqrt 2(9+3i)(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
Then, solving
$$16-a=\sqrt 2(8\cos\theta-2\sin\theta)$$
$$9-b=\sqrt 2(8\sin\theta+2\cos\theta)$$
$$16-a=\sqrt 2(9\cos\theta-3\sin\theta)$$
$$11-b=\sqrt 2(9\sin\theta+3\cos\theta)$$
gives
$$a=10,\quad b=-1,\quad \theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Thus, the coordinate you want is
$$\sqrt 2(3+4i)\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+(10-i)=9+6i,$$
i.e.
$$\color{red}{(9,6)}$$

Comment: The solution looks more like $(9,8)$.

Comment: @mvw: I thought so, but later I began to believe that the figure of the 'new' rectangle is not correct, for example, the side lengths of the 'new' rectangle should be $3\sqrt 2,7\sqrt 2$, but the figure has $4\sqrt 2,6\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @mathlove thanks for your help. I will rate your answer as correct! I only have one more little question, how can this formula be refactored? Is it possible to get one formula where I simply put the points in it? Would this be possible? Thanks again from Germany

Comment: @JohnSmith: You are welcome. For example, $\sqrt 2(8+2i)(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ means that we rotate a point $8+2i$ about the origin by $\theta$ (counterclockwise) and expand it by $\sqrt 2$. Also, $+(10-i)$ is a translation. So, in this question, if you have a point $(A,B)$, then you can get the 'new' point $(C,D)$ by solving $C+Di=\sqrt 2(A+Bi)(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})+(10-i)$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @JohnSmith: We have $C=A-B+10,D=A+B-1$. So, if you have a point $(A,B)$, then you know that the 'new' point is at $(A-B+10,A+B-1)$.

Comment: Your solution makes assumptions, like a uniform scaling by $\sqrt{2}$ which is not justified by the given data (two points and their transformed images). We could now argue if it is better to make up data or take it from the drawing.

Comment: @mvw yes you are totally right! Is it possible to get this scaling factor?  I would like to know how to get the scaling factor for both sides?  Thanks

Comment: @mathlove I tried some variants and come to a similar conclusion: the points and their images do not match the original rectangle and the image of the rectangle. The drawing seems wrong.

Comment: @mathlove E.g. using $C1=(9,2)^T$ and $C2=(17,10)^T$  as another data pair, will lead to a transform which maps $(3,4)^T$ to $(9,6)^T$, like in your result.  +1 for you for first noting that the drawing is inconsistent.

Comment: @mathlove Hey I had to write you back, I think when writing my question I was not specific enough. In my examples the origin rectangle is always  located at the `(0,0)` point in the coordinate system. It means the rectangle is always located horizontal, means the right-bottom vetric is at (0, (0 -999)) . I think that makes an difference in the calculation right? Isnt it easier like this?

Comment: @JohnSmith: (0,(0-999)) means (0,-999)? And what are the side-lengths? Please write the coordinate of the four vertices of the rectangle. Also, uniform scaling, or not?

Comment: @mathlove The side lengths are 7 and 3. The coordinates are 0,0;  0,3;  7,3 7,0   Is it now easier to calculate?

Comment: @JohnSmith: And uniform scaling? Also, what are the known points? what are the known 'new' points?

Answer (score 1):

Your transformation contains translation (2 parameter), rotation (1 parameter) and stretching, which I hope means scaling (1 parameter).

This in general is no linear but an affine transform, except for the case that the origin gets mapped to the origin, which I doubt here.

The transform would be like this, using homogeneous coordinates:
$$
T = \left(
\begin{matrix}
t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} \\
t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad (*)
$$

Assuming we first do the translation, then the roation, then the scaling we get a matrix:
\begin{align}
T 
&=
T_\text{scale} \, T_\text{rot} \, T_\text{trans} \\
&=  
\left(
\begin{matrix}
s & 0 & 0 \\
0 & s & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & t_x \\
0 & 1 & t_y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\\
&= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
s \cos \theta & -s \sin \theta & 0 \\
s \sin \theta & s \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & t_x \\
0 & 1 & t_y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\\
&= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
s \cos \theta & -s \sin \theta & s(t_x \cos \theta - t_y \sin \theta) \\
s \sin \theta & s \cos \theta & s(t_x \sin \theta + t_y \cos \theta) \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{align}

Your two points give four equations, it might be enough to determine the four parameters $t_x, t_y, \theta, s$.

Inserting the points and their images 
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
s \cos \theta & -s \sin \theta & s(t_x \cos \theta - t_y \sin \theta) \\
s \sin \theta & s \cos \theta & s(t_x \sin \theta + t_y \cos \theta) \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
y_1 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x_2 \\
y_2 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
leads to the equations
$$
\cos \theta - \sin \theta = 0 \\
\sin \theta + \cos \theta = 2
$$
where the second one has no real solution. So this is not working.

Looking at the rectangle, the ratio of the sides seems to have changed.

This means we have
\begin{align}
T 
&= 
T_\text{scale} \, T_\text{rot} \, T_\text{trans} \\
&= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
s & 0 & 0 \\
0 & t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & t_x \\
0 & 1 & t_y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\\
&= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
s \cos \theta & -s \sin \theta & 0 \\
t \sin \theta & t \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & t_x \\
0 & 1 & t_y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\\
&= 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
s \cos \theta & -s \sin \theta & s(t_x \cos \theta - t_y \sin \theta) \\
t \sin \theta & t \cos \theta & t(t_x \sin \theta + t_y \cos \theta) \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{align}
And we end up with five parameters $t_x, t_y, \theta, s, t$ and only four equations.

This agrees with the six unknowns of equation $(*)$ and making use of the property of the rotation that $1 = \text{det}(R) = \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta$. I fail to spot a fifth equation so far.

Update: It seems the given data $A1, B1, A2, B2$ does not match the other part of the drawing, especially the original rectangle boundary and its transformed image.

Comment: @nvw Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to determin the four parameters with the Coordinates I have? Thanks

Comment: @mnv Great answer! The drawing is not exact, but I think we can consider that the rectangle is scaled the same for both axis. But I also have to say that I know this formulas, but for me it would be more intresting, how to calculate with the real coordinates. Maybe you could place in the example coordinates I gave you? Thanks for your help! It would rate your answer as correct! Thanks again!

Comment: I used the coordinates you gave and they are not allowing the scaling to be uniform ($s = t$), they lead to the two funny equations for sine and cosine which have no solution for a $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Maybe you could use other example coordinates? Choose one ? Thanks you are really helpful

Comment: Hi thanks, so `tx,ty` is the scaling right? And `θ,s` is for the rotation. When I caculate `atan(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI` i get degress so can I use that?

Comment: No, $t_x$ and $t_y$ are the translations in $x$- and $y$-direction. $\theta$ is the angle of the rotation and $s$ is the scaling in $x$-direction while $t$ is the scaling in $y$-direction, I should have named them $s_x$ and $s_y$ for more consistency.

Comment: @nvw Hey I had to write you back, I think when writing my question I was not specific enough. In my examples the origin rectangle is always  located at the `(0,0)` point in the coordinate system. It means the rectangle is always located horizontal, means the right-bottom vetric is at (0, (0 -999)) . I think that makes an difference in the calculation right? Isnt it easier like this?

Comment: @JohnSmith Individual discussion is not good. Clarifications of the problem should be discussed under the question not the answers.